# Variable being assigned a function instead of a value

Tags: swift, function

I have the following code in swift to check execution time:

```
let q = NSDate();
... // Some code here
let r = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(q);
print("Execution time is \(r)");
```

Every time this executes, it prints "Execution time is (function)".
I even verified that the type of `r` is `(NSDate) -> NSTimeInterval`. How can i set `r` equal to the `NSTimeInterval` itself?

Comment: What is the variable s?

Comment: you have defined `r` not `s`

Comment: That's the main problem when you don't properly name your vars

Comment: No i just deleted the other bit, it should've been `r`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `NSDate.timeIntervalSinceDate` is a method on the NSDate class. You are creating a function object from that method that has the variable already filled in, but it still needs to be called on an object.

The simple fix is as follows:

```
    let q = NSDate()
    // other code here
    let r = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(q)
    print("Execution time is \(r)")
```

Another option would be to do this:

```
    let q = NSDate()
    // other code here
    let r = q.timeIntervalSinceNow
    print("Execution time is \(r)")
```

Comment: Ah, I seem to have missed that! Thank you.